# Check if a folder/directory exists then display html1, if not display html2

Tags: php, directory

I am trying to add custom html to a 404 page in wordpress.

```
<?php           
$filename = "/find";
if (!file_exists($filename))
echo $filename, " display html2 ";
elseif (!is_dir($filename))
echo $filename, " display html1 ";
?>
```

If someone visits http://www.demosite.com/about/whatever = Display HTML 1

If someone visits http://www.demosite.com/find/whatever = Display HTML 2

Is this even possible with PHP and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php           
$filename = "/find";
if (is_dir($filename)){
echo $filename, " display html1 ";
include('html1.html');
}
else{
echo $filename, " display html2 ";
include('html1.html');
}
?>
```

This code checks for the folder "find" if it exists it shows html1 else html2.

**I guess the better option for you will be this :**

Use htaccess when user `browse http://yourdomain/about/whatever` show the contents from `http://yourdomain/page.php?p=about&var=whatever`

And get the value of p in your page using `$_GET['p']`, and show the html accordingly

```
if($_GET['p'] == "find"){
   include('html1.html');
}else{
   include('html2.html');
}
```

Comment: that checks to see if there's a file within the directory. I don't want it to look for a file. I just want the php code to see that the user is either within the directory or not, then what kind of html to display.

Comment: It actually checks for the folder "find", Do you really have a find and about folder or are you using htaccess redirect.

Comment: I'm trying:

    <?php           
    $filename = "/find";
    if (is_dir($filename)){
    echo "<h1>hello</h1>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<h1>nope</h1>";
    }
    ?>

But it doesn't work. The word "nope" appears on both:

http://www.demosite.com/about/whatever

http://www.demosite.com/find/whatever

I'd like to have "hello" appear under the /find/whatever pages.

Comment: It is because directory "/find" doesn't exists or the path is wrong

Comment: the directory is there... what other way of writing the path could there be? I added -  /home/user/public_html/demosite.com/find but that didnt work either?

Comment: Give relative path based on from where you are executing the php file.if your php file is in root give `$filename = './find';` Note the `dot(.)` before `/`

Comment: Still providing a "nope" under both of them :( do you think the wordpress 404.php is causing it to do this?

Comment: @Mike : sorry mike i don't know wordpress